# How to trigger a rescan of available disks for installation during Ubuntu 18.04 Server live install (subiquity installer)?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

As noted below, because of a few missing pieces in the default/standard installer, there were some manual steps to get the volume we want to install 18.04 reachable. I'm to the point that the volume is mounted. However, the installer doesn't see it. I assume because some check or scan runs before my manual work is done.

A.) Is there a way to re-run the "available volumes to install to" in the new Subiquity installer?

The old installer seemed to have said feature (there was a menu item). The pain is I can't use the old installer as the `bnx2i` module is missing and I can't install `iscsiuio` via apt like the new installer. Perhaps that's a second/separate question:

B.) Could rebuilding the 18.04 old installer version with the kernel module and apt package needed be an easier route?

(**A.** is the primary question, but asked **B.** just in case anyone's been down that path.)

**Additional Info on Specific Use Case:**

We've purchased a HPE BL460c Gen9. These have HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 536FLB Network Adapters (which has Qlogic internal components). These interfaces require the `bnx2x` firmware. We've connected these to a SAN via iSCSI, thus the `bnx2i` and `iscsi_ibft` linux modules are needed. Plus `iscsiuio` needs installed.

In the current 18.04 server installer, when trying to enable these 10G network interface, the firmware for the `bnx2x` can't be found (check `dmesg` command). So we have to download the firmware manually from [Linux Kernel Firmware Repo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/) and copy the specific `bnx2x*.fw` file the `dmesg` command errors about to `/lib/firmware/bnx2x`. All these manual steps allow us to read the iBFT (iSCSI Boot Firmware Table) and login to the iSCSI target with `iscsistart -b`. Additionally, I've partitioned and mounted the iSCSI volumes and can see them in `df -h`. At this point is where I'm stuck at with the installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `sudo subiquity` will start the installer again in the new tty you are running the shell in. This initially solved this specific problem, however the installer fails later on. What did work was killing the process from tty2:

```bsh
kill -9 "$(ps aux | grep subiquity | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')"
```

This restarts the installer on tty1, shows the iSCSI volumes at the disk selection step and properly installs.

I specifically still have an issue during the boot process, but the above fixes everything for the question.

Comment: The suggested command does not work as is since awk will output newlines between process ids. I use this instead : `ps aux | grep subiquit | grep -v grep | awk  '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9`. Otherwise good answer, had the same problem and restarting subiquity indeed rescans the drives.